# undefined method `image' in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip, erb

I am using Paperclip, and my only problem is that in my image tag, I have an undefined method "image".

```
<%= image_tag @posts.image.url(:medium) %>
```

is where my error is occurring. When I loaded a new migration, I accidentally did "rails g paperclip user image" instead of "rails g paperclip posts image" so I went into my code and changed "user" to "posts." I asked something similar and someone mentioned that it was with my schema.rb file(?).

Just to be safe, this is my post controller:

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
    end

    def new
        @post = Post.new

        if @post.save
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        @post.save

        redirect_to @post
    end

    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])

        if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :body))
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @post.destroy

        redirect_to root_path
    end


    private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :image)
    end
end
```

but here is my migration file:

```
class AddAttachmentImageToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :posts do |t|
      t.attachment :image
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :posts, :image
  end
end
```

and my user.rb file:

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { large: '600x600>', medium: '300x300>', thumb: '150x150#' }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

Comment: I guess it would be `@post.image`.

Comment: that's where the problem is

Comment: `@posts` i think is the collection of `post` objects. you need to fetch `image` for each `post`. so you need to traverse the `@posts` and and for each `post` you can use this `<%= image_tag post.image.url(:medium) %>` that would work i guess.

Comment: so you're suggesting to get rid of the `@` ? I don't think that'll work

Comment: nah im not saying getting rid of `@` im suggesting that please traverse the list of `@posts` and try to get `image` for each post

Comment: I've only been on Rails for a month or so, and I don't know _traverse_  `@posts` for `image`, to be honest.... plus, I'm trying to learn this from [mackenziechild](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5W-Y3aROVE)

Comment: no worries. for your case i will share the code below as answer, if it meets your requirement you can use that, but i would suggest you to please go through this as well http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_iterators.htm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90125/discussion-between-athar-and-brendon-baughn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments and your code, it looks like your `@posts` variable is either empty or undefined. To add to the original answer, here's what I'd do:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ActionController::Base
   def index
      @posts = Post.all.order(created_at: :desc)
   end
end

#app/views/posts/index.html.erb
<% if @posts.any? %>
   <% @posts.each do |post| %>
       <%= image_tag post.image.url(:medium) %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You *must* have the `@posts` variable referenced in the `view` which corresponds to the `action` you're running. From seeing your comments, it appears this might not be the case.

You need to be referencing single instances of the `Post` model, in order to have the `image` method available.

If it is not available, it either means you don't have the `@posts` variable declared properly, or your `Paperclip` gem is not set up properly.

---

> this is my user.rb file

haha okay. THIS is the problem.

Make sure you put this in your `post.rb` file:

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { large: '600x600>', medium: '300x300>', thumb: '150x150#' }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Paperclip basically links stored images to database records. Thus, in order to append the `image` method to your model, you have to have the `Paperclip` options appended to it.

Putting the paperclip calls in `user.rb` will add the `image` method to your `User` model. You need to put those lines in the `Post` model.

BTW I met the guys who made Paperclip:

[image]

---

> that it was with my schema.rb file(?).

The `schema.rb` file is located in `/config/db/schema.rb`.

Essentially, each time you *migrate* to your DB, the `schema` is updated, so that in the event you need to repopulate the db, Rails will be able to pull a pre-built set of SQL calls to do it.

> Indeed, it is recommended that you use `rake db:schema:load` to
>   rebuild a database (rather than `rake db:migrate`). HOWEVER (VERY
>   IMPORTANT), **IT DELETES ANY DATA** in that database, making it
>   unadvisable to use it for anything other than building new db's.

You can [read about Schema.rb here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).

In regards to what your friend was saying, if you go into your `schema.rb` file, you'll be able to see which table has the paperclip columns added to it. By generating the migration for the `users` table, you may have caused a conflict.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I got the answer after moving into the discussion. You're right about moving the code into my `Posts.rb` file

Answer (score 2):

You need to access image for one post at a time so you need to traverse the posts collection and fetch image for each post like this

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= image_tag post.image.url(:medium) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'll just get an undefined method error, even though I used `<% @posts.each do |post| %>` in a different file

Comment: how are you getting `@posts` can you share that code

Comment: [github](https://github.com/BBaughn1/savings) <-- it's in my github. If you need to know my posts controller and my user.rb file, it'll be updated in my question

Comment: well try this in `rails console` and see it should crash `@posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')` you are calling `order` on `Post.all` and it should crash bcoz `.all` returns `array` and you are trying to order array which should crash i think. Secondly in `posts_controller` `index` action do this `@posts = Post.order('created_at DESC')` and then try to use my code in answer for displaying image it should work

Comment: not working, still have the exact same error `undefined method '.each'`

Comment: please join this http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90125/discussion-between-athar-and-brendon-baughn

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be how you changing "user" to "posts.".it would be okay to just change controller or view name,but change model is a different thing that you have to generate a migration to change table name